# React: Is there something similar to node.textContent?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I'm trying to test a react component children and I wanted to get a text representation of its children.

Is there a tool that does something similar to `node.textContent` for React?

I would like to have something like this:

```
let testComponent = (
  <Test>
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>abc2</p>
  </Test>
);

expect(testComponent.props.children.toString()).to.equal('abc abc2');
```

Comment: `react-testing-library` might be the answer to this and many other questions you may have concerning frontend code tests. Don't test for internal details, test for what a user actually sees.

Answer (score 33):

[image: react-getNodeText Sandbox screenshot]

```
// this is an out of date version, use the one below
const getNodeText = node => {
  if (['string', 'number'].includes(typeof node)) return node
  if (node instanceof Array) return node.map(getNodeText).join('')
  if (typeof node === 'object' && node) return getNodeText(node.props.children)
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-getnodetext-h21ss

```
// in the screenshot above

const heading = <Heading>Hello <span className="red">Code</span>Sandbox</Heading>

return (
  <div>
    {heading}
    <pre ref={printInnerHTML}/>
    <pre>{getNodeText(heading)}</pre>
  </div>
)
```

---

### TypeScript update

```
const getNodeText = (node: React.ReactNode): string => {
  if (node == null) return ''

  switch (typeof node) {
    case 'string':
    case 'number':
      return node.toString()

    case 'boolean':
      return ''

    case 'object': {
      if (node instanceof Array)
        return node.map(getNodeText).join('')

      if ('props' in node)
        return getNodeText(node.props.children)
    } // eslint-ignore-line no-fallthrough

    default: 
      console.warn('Unresolved `node` of type:', typeof node, node)
      return ''
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome solution :)

Comment: for those of you who got confused like me by `typeof node === 'object' && node`, the type of `null` is `object`, so this check protects against null.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small function that traverses through the react element and gets you the text.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

const MyComponent = ()=>{
  return <div>
    <p>hello</p>
    <div>
      <p>to</p>
    </div>
  </div>
}

const getText=(tree)=>{
  if(typeof tree === 'string'){
    return tree;
  }
  return tree.children.map((child)=>{
    return getText(child);
  }).join('');
}


it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<MyComponent />)
    .toJSON();

  expect(getText(tree)).toBe("helloto");
});
```

Here MyComponent is the component from which you need the text.

getText() will get all the text nodes from the component in the form of a string.

Comment: You also need to handle `boolean`, `number`, `null` which are all possible types for `tree`, see [`type React.ReactNode`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L203)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getDomNode()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode) or [findDomNode()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode) for es6 Components, and then use normal DOM methods.

If your'e looking for the React way - There shouldn't be one, since a parent is quite blind of its children.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AirBnB’s Enzyme library

```
shallow(<Foo>bar</Foo>).text  // bar
```

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md#text--string

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should try [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) (I usually use it together with the [React Testing Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)). Basically, you can take [a snapshot of your component](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing), so, you can test not only the text contained in your component, but you can also test the layout, the parameters of the elements, etc. It is very handy to detect unwanted changes. It also comes with great features as [code coverage](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#coverage):

```
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MyComponent } from "./MyComponent";

describe("MyComponent", (): void => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  it("renders properly", (): void => {
    const { container } = render(
      <MyComponent prop1="myprop1" prop2="myprop2" />
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```