# Get text content from node in React

Tags: reactjs, dom

Having a bit of trouble pulling text from a node.

The node is a paragraph.

```
 <p className="Blend" refs="hello"> { `${this.state.landing}?utm_campaign=${this.state.utm}` } </p>
```

I’m trying to log the contents of the node to the console in a function.

```
 makeSmall = () => {
        var text = this.refs.hello.innerText
        console.log(text)
      }
```

However, this console is not returning anything. I've tried accessing the node with via className as well.

What's the proper way to access text in React?

Comment: I believe you have a type in your `<p>` element on the `refs` attribute, this should be `ref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for contributing. There were a few mistakes in my previous approach.

Namely, trying to set the ref in a function. Below are the steps I took to make it work.

1) construct the ref using React.createRef(); ([new in react 16](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html))

```
class Newone extends Component {
    state = {
        allocation: "Acq",
      };
      textUrl = React.createRef();
```

2) append the ref to the appropriate node

```
 <p className="Blend" ref={this.textUrl}> { `${this.state.landing}?utm_campaign=${this.state.utm}` } </p>
```

3) reference the ref using value.innertext

```
handleLinkClick = (event) => {
bitly.shorten(this.textUrl.value.innerText)
```

**Make sure you are using React version 16.3.0-alpha.1.

Below are screenshots of the console.

bitly.shorten(this.textUrl)
[image: enter image dfs here]

bitly.shorten(this.textUrl.value)
[image]

bitly.shorten(this.textUrl.value.innerText)
[image]

Make sure to append innerText if you only want to return the text in the node.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

[image: react-getNodeText Sandbox screenshot]

```
const getNodeText = node => {
  if (['string', 'number'].includes(typeof node)) return node
  if (node instanceof Array) return node.map(getNodeText).join('')
  if (typeof node === 'object' && node) return getNodeText(node.props.children)
}

const printHTML = ref => ref && (ref.innerText = document.querySelector('h1').outerHTML)
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-getnodetext-h21ss

```
  // in the picture
  {heading} // <Heading>Hello <span className="red">Code</span>Sandbox</Heading>
  <pre ref={printHTML}/>
  <pre>{getNodeText(heading)}</pre>
```

*originally from here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564620/985454](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564620/985454_)*

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `<p>` attributes,

You wrote:

```
<p className="Blend" refs="hello"> { `${this.state.landing}?utm_campaign=${this.state.utm}` } </p>
```

This should be:

```
<p className="Blend" ref="hello"> { `${this.state.landing}?utm_campaign=${this.state.utm}` } </p>
```

The `refs` attribute is the faulty one, this should be `ref`

For reference: (check the browser console or the in-site console) [See this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5v5o6r2qwp)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need save the text for the paragraph into the state and show it. So you will know this value:

```
 state = { msg: `${landing}?utm_campaign=${utm}` } 
 ...
 <p className="Blend"> { ${this.state.msg} } </p>
```